# Sorting Multi Index in Pandas differently for each level

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dataframe, multi-index

I have a dataframe with an index of 3 levels. I need to sort the index by each level but in different ways. What can achieve this?

Have a dataframe (`df`) as:

```
                     other columns
color shape    count              
red   circle   1                 x
      triangle 3                 x
               2                 x
blue  circle   4                 x
      triangle 2                 x
```

and I want a new `df` where `color` is sorted `ascending`, `shape` is `descending`, and `count` is `ascending`:

```
                     other columns
color shape       count              
blue  triangle    2                 x
      circle      4                 x
red   triangle    2                 x
                  3                 x
      circle      1                 x
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `ascending` parameter with a list of booleans:

```
df.sort_index(ascending=[True, False, True])
```

Output:

```
                     other columns
color shape    count              
blue  triangle 2                 x
      circle   4                 x
red   triangle 2                 x
               3                 x
      circle   1                 x
```